# mongoose update: $set and $push not update anything?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How can I update mongo with $set and $push?

I have the data below:

```
[ { _id: 57682f69feaf405c51fdf144,
    email: 'testuser1@testdomain.com',
    username: 'testuser' },
  { username: 'sevilayha', _id: 5768d36c4c243de7422f681e, __v: 0 } ]
```

In my express app.js:

```
// With Mongoose, everything is derived from a Schema. Let's get a reference to it and define our users.
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    admin: Boolean,
    location: String,
    meta: {
      age: Number,
      website: String
    },
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
});

// The next step is compiling our schema into a Model.
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {

   var updateQuery = {};

   User.findOne({ username: /^sevilayha/ }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    updateQuery["meta"] = {
      date: Date.now()
    }
    user.update({
      $push: updateQuery,
      $set: { size: 'large' },
      email: 'test@example.com'
    });
    res.status(200).json(user);
  });
  User.find(function (err, users) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(users);
  });
```

I still get the same data. Nothing updated, set or pushed. Any ideas what I have missed?

I'm on "mongoose": "~4.5.1"

Comment: I believe you should add user.save() after updating the data so the new values are reflected in the db.

Comment: nope. no need of that. tested with save() as well but no luck.

Comment: Did you try not using `.update`, but using `.save` instead like so: ```Model.findOne({ name: 'borne' }, function (err, doc){
  doc.name = 'jason borne';
  doc.visits.$inc();
  doc.save();
});``` as taken from the mongoose documentation?

Comment: which documentation are you following from mongoose?

Comment: i think save() is deprecated or no longer in use.

Comment: Yeah, my bad! I was looking at 2.* docs. I still find it weird that you aren't passing a callback function to the update call as there might be some errors while processing the query. You could try adding a callback and returning the result after it has been fired as it is possible that the model is updated once the operation is completed against the db

Comment: `$push` is [meant for arrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/), but `meta` isn't an array. Also, both `size` and `email` aren't part of your schema.

Comment: Thanks for spotting those out. But it is still very strange because I have to add the callback in otherwise it won't work!

Answer (score 0):

I updated my schema but I must add the callback or it won't work:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: false },
    email: String,
    admin: Boolean,
    location: String,
    meta: {
      age: Number,
      website: String
    },
    data: Array,
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
});

var updateQuery = {};
  User.findOne({ username: /^sevilayha/ }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    updateQuery["data"] = {
      date: Date.now()
    }
    user.update({
      $push: updateQuery,
      $set: { location: 'large' },
      name: 'John',
      email: 'test2@example.com'
    }, function(err, res) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      res.status(200).json(res);
    });
  });
```

How odd!